# How can I create a 2d array out of a normal array through splitting each element (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, concatenation

I have got a very large string, it contains about 13000 times different data of the same kind. I have now created a function to split this string into an array of 13000 elements. Now each element of those 13000 still consists out of different data seperated with spaces (it looks something like: `20.8967489 50.29868 3 9867 86983648`
How can I create a 2 dimensional array storing 5 elements for each of the 13000 elements?

I have tried something like this:

```
function getValuableData(){
    const fullData = [[]];
        text.replace('   ','  ');
        text.replace('  ',' ');
        const data = text.split('a')
    data.forEach(element => {
        const singleData = element.split(' ')
        fullData.concat(singleData)
    });
    }
```

Here is a litte section of the string: 'a1 7.0 20.172778040000026 63.561680508000052 2 2.0 a1 8.0 20.186170638000021 63.565585974000044 3 3.0 a1 9.0 20.195506026000032 63.572607051000034 4 4.0 a1 10.0 20.20404755800007 63.580019088000029 5 5.0 a1 11.0 20.212622636000049 63.587417993000031 6 6.0'

Comment: If there is a single step from this very large string towards the 2d array I would of course also accept it as an answer.

Comment: Sounds like you need to search for chunking

Comment: can you provide example input string and the output from it? like 3 elements in the top level result array?

Comment: `text.replace('   ','  ');         text.replace('  ',' '); ` - this doesn't make sense. strings are immutable

Comment: Also are the numbers always the same length? Padded for example

`20.8967489 50.29868 3 9867 86983648 20.8960000  0.20000 3    7 
     648` - because if not, chunking will not work

Comment: Thanks for the input, what is the expected OUTPUT since you have 2 floats and 3 ints in your first example and split on `a` but you have 3 floats, 1 int and another float, and have `a1` as separator in your second example!

Comment: The split is only on 'a', the one is the first float. So I have six floats in total. Sorry, it is not 5 it is 6. My first example was much more random.

Comment: the output should be a 2D-Array: [[1,7.0,20.172778040000026,63.561680508000052,2,2.0],[1,8.0,20.186170638000021,63.565585974000044,3,3.0],[...],...13000 times data...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Let see how we can get a 2 dimensional array storing 5 elements for each using single for loop**

- update your `getValuableData` function

```
function getValuableData(){
       text.replace('   ','  ');
       text.replace('  ',' ');
       return text.split('a');
 }
```

- convert above split result to 2 dimensional array with single loop

```
function get2Dimensional() {
        const oneDimArray = getValuableData();
        const rows = [];
        const itemsPerRow = 5;

        for (let i = 0; i < oneDimArray.length; i += itemsPerRow) {
            const row = oneDimArray.slice(i, i + itemsPerRow);
            rows.push(row);
        }

        return rows;
  }
```

Comment: `text.replace('   ','  ');  text.replace('  ',' ');` does nothing whatsoever to any data. Also the slice is a very expensive operation

Comment: thank you for comment, method getValuableData kind of pseudo code in  my answer , from my understanding question need method get2Dimensional

Answer (score 1):

I'd `map` this array and split each element:

```js
const text = 'a1 7.0 20.172778040000026 63.561680508000052 2 2.0 a1 8.0 20.186170638000021 63.565585974000044 3 3.0 a1 9.0 20.195506026000032 63.572607051000034 4 4.0 a1 10.0 20.20404755800007 63.580019088000029 5 5.0 a1 11.0 20.212622636000049 63.587417993000031 6 6.0'; 
const result = 
    text.split(/\s*a\s*/)          // First split
        .filter(x => x)            // Remove empty strings
        .map(x => x.split(/\s+/)); // Second split

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This for some reason did not work.

Comment: @Paul care to elaborate?

Comment: I have tried several variations of "const result = 
    text.split(/\s*a\s*/)
        .map(x => x.split(/\s+/));", especially changing the inside of the brackets to 'a' and ' ', as I didn't get why there is that many '/' etc.; however nothing created a 2d array filled with the data mentioned. I can't clearify it further as I don't know where my problem lies.

Comment: @Paul can you share a (small!) example of the original `text` value? perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I have already found a solution through using the text-cleaner online tool, but to make this question complete, here is a litte section of the string: 'a1 7.0 20.172778040000026 63.561680508000052 2 2.0 a1 8.0 20.186170638000021 63.565585974000044 3 3.0 a1 9.0 20.195506026000032 63.572607051000034 4 4.0 a1 10.0 20.20404755800007 63.580019088000029 5 5.0 a1 11.0 20.212622636000049 63.587417993000031 6 6.0'

Comment: @Paul the solution generated a redundant empty entry (handled by adding a `filter` call), but other than that it seems to have fit your brief - see the executable snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have spaces around your split character you can use `String::indexOf()` to navigate by spaces in a big string, faster than splitting by a regex:

```
` Chrome/119
---------------------------------------------------
Alexander   1.00x  |  x100  123  224  233  240  256
Mureinik    2.08x  |  x100  256  264  270  275  282
---------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const str = '20.8967489 50.29868 3 9867 86983648';

let longStr = '';
let count = 13000;
while(count--) longStr += (longStr ? ' a ' : '') + str;

//@benchmark Mureinik
longStr.split(/\s*a\s*/)          // First split
        .map(x => x.split(/\s+/));


//@benchmark Alexander

const result = [];
let chunk = [], prev = 0, next;
while((next = longStr.indexOf(' ', prev)) > 0){
  chunk.push(longStr.slice(prev, prev = next));
  prev++;
  if(longStr[prev] === 'a'){
    result.push(chunk);
    chunk = [];
    prev+=2;
  }
}

result.push(chunk);
result;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: What's with the obfuscation at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 5 numbers per set and want arrays of 5 items as numbers

```js
// Split the string into individual components
const components = data.slice(3).split(' a1 '); // drop the first a1 and split on the rest

// Initialize the 2D array
const dataArray = [];

// Loop through the components 
for (let i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    dataArray.push(components[i].trim().split(' ').map(num=>+num))
}
console.log(dataArray);
```

```html
<script>
/* Generate testdata based on this example data from OP

a1 7.0 20.172778040000026 63.561680508000052 2 2.0 a1 8.0 20.186170638000021 63.565585974000044 3 3.0 a1 9.0 20.195506026000032 63.572607051000034 4 4.0 a1 10.0 20.20404755800007 63.580019088000029 5 5.0 a1 11.0 20.212622636000049 63.587417993000031 6 6.0

*/

const numberOfSets = 100; // change to 13000 to test your size

// Random float between min and max
const randomFloat = (min, max) => (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
// Random integer between min and max
const randomInt = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

// Generate a single data set
const generateRandomData = () => 
    `${randomFloat(1, 20).toFixed(1)} ${randomFloat(10, 70).toFixed(14)} ${randomFloat(1, 60).toFixed(1)} ${randomInt(1, 10)} ${randomFloat(1,10).toFixed(1)}`;

// Generate data sets and join them into a single string
const data = `a1 ${Array.from({ length: numberOfSets }, generateRandomData).join(' a1 ')}`;
console.log(data);
</script>
```